# Is there a way to iterate over Spark RDD partitions without using mapping?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

I'm currently using `graphframes` to generate a graph and then I need to find the paths between all vertices. (That is all pairs of vertices are tested to find the minimum path between them.)

Both `bfs` and `find` in `graphframes` generate dataframes meaning they cannot be used in any kind of mapping function. Is there a way I can work around this? (For instance, doing a for loop on all RDD entries in a partition [`mapPartitions` doesn't work, I tried it.])

Comment: It might be possibble to use bfs or find, and just map the output of that back to an RDD before returning. Would that work?

Comment: @DavisBroda I tried that, it seems Spark doesn't care, if at any point inside the map you create a dataframe or RDD it throws an error.